# FlashDevelop breakpoints for Haxe CPP, allowing "Step-Into" functionality?

Tags: windows, breakpoints, haxe, step-into

Is there a way to set a break-point in FlashDevelop when targeting a Haxe/NME program for windows? It is very hard to follow the logic of a bug if I cannot step into the code.

Comment: If I am debugging logic for NME, then I just switch back to flash target, and debug using FlashDevelops built in debug tools. Might not be an option for every situation.

Answer (score 3):

In this [post](http://haxeflixel.com/forum/help/using-visual-c-for-debugging-cpp-target-with-breakpoints) you can find an example visual studio project that allow you to debug cpp target.